# sh with crontab is not working in Centos

Tags: linux, shell, sh, cron

I am testing an sh script with crontab which simply creates a file

```
 #!/bin/bash
    PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin
    TMP_FILE=/home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/i_am_running
    touch "$TMP_FILE"
```

Now I want to run it on crontab and have used the following but failed

```
18 10 * * * sh /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello.sh
```

Also this one

```
18 10 * * * usr/bin/sh /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello.sh
```

I am also trying this

```
23 12 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello.sh
23 12 * * * sh /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello1.sh
23 12 * * * /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello2.sh
```

Anyone knows whats the problem?

Solution:
23 12 * * * sh /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello1.sh

This works!

Comment: Where is `$TMP_FILE` defined? If it's in your own environment, then cron doesn't know about it.

Comment: Canonical shell location is `/bin/sh`, not `/usr/bin/sh`.

Comment: i just need to creat a file to check the shell ran. i think its not defined:(

Answer (score 1):

Give the full path to the shell from cron starting with '/':

```
18 10 * * * /usr/bin/sh /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello.sh
```

Or just leave the shell out and run the script directly if it is executable:

```
18 10 * * * /home/hmm/AppFlatForRent/hello.sh
```

Comment: But you didn;t start with "/".  you have "usr/bin/sh", not "/usr/bin/sh"

Comment: tried without sh. not working. is there anything wrong with the test script?

Comment: Also as @glenn jackman pointed out where is TMP_FILE defined?  If not defined you are touching nothing.

Comment: can u suggest me another simple test? i think there is something wrong with the TEMP_FILE